# Manter a classe original de um valor importado de SQL para o R

Tags: r

Importei uma tabela de um banco SQL, mas, o R está automaticamente convertendo os valores de uma coluna de `character` para `num` e preciso que ele os preserve na classe `character`. Parece que isso ocorre porque o pacote `RODBC` se comporta semelhante ao Excel.

Dados da tabela que será importada:

```
TABLE_CAT TABLE_SCHEM           TABLE_NAME             COLUMN_NAME DATA_TYPE TYPE_NAME COLUMN_SIZE BUFFER_LENGTH
5  BI_TOXICOLOGIA         dbo TA_HISTORICO_PETICAO             NU_PROCESSO        12   varchar          21            21
6  BI_TOXICOLOGIA         dbo TA_HISTORICO_PETICAO           NU_EXPEDIENTE        12   varchar          21            21
```

As colunas `NU_PROCESSO` e `NU_EXPEDIENTE`, são cadeias numéricas, mas precisam continuar no formato `CHAR`.

Utilizei o pacote `RODBC` para importar a tabela:

```
con <- odbcConnect("BISQL", uid = "login", pwd = "senha")
ANVS_base_completa_temp <- sqlFetch(con, "TA_HISTORICO_PETICAO")
```

No resultado as colunas estão vindo como `NUM` e acabo perdendo a integridade dos dados. Mesmo que eu as converta novamente para `character`.

```
str(ANVS_base_completa_temp)
'data.frame':   193137 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ NU_PROCESSO            : num  2.54e+16 2.54e+16 2.54e+16 2.54e+16 2.54e+16 ...
 $ NU_EXPEDIENTE          : num  1.47e+08 1.38e+08 1.26e+08 1.13e+08 7.79e+07 ...
```

Alguém sabe como posso importar essa tabela sem que o R faça a converção desses dados? De repente usando algum outro pacote isso funcione?

Comment: Tentou: `ANVS_base_completa_temp <- sqlFetch(con, "TA_HISTORICO_PETICAO", as.is = TRUE)`?

Comment: Não acredito. Algo tão simples e eu aqui sendo humilhado.haha.. Funcionou perfeitamente. Muito Obrigado, Neves.